# volume and curvature of submanifolds

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Suppose an $m$-dimensional manifold in an $n$-dimensional euclidean space, choose some point on this manifold and take an $n$-dimensional ball of certain radius $R$ centred in this point. If the volume of the manifold "enclosed" in this ball is $V$, what can we tell about the bounds for the different types of curvatures for the manifold inside this ball?
Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer by any means, but a pretty and germane elementary theorem:

If $S$ is a sphere in $\mathbf{R}^3$ having radius $R_0$ and *passing through* the origin $O$, $R$ is a real number such that $0 < R \leq 2R_0$, and $\Sigma_R$ is the sphere of radius $R$ centered at $O$, then the area of the portion of $S$ inside $\Sigma_R$ is $\pi R^2$. (!)

Philosophically, the volume (here, area) of $S$ inside $\Sigma_R$ cannot distinguish $S$ (with constant positive curvature) from a flat plane until $R > 2R_0$.

Comment: $\Sigma_R$ is the sphere of radius $R$ in terms of geodesic distance, being $\Sigma$ a submanifold of $\mathbf{R}^3$, right? Is it extensible to other dimensions?

Comment: @bourbaquez: Here $R$ is the (extrinsic) Euclidean distance. I haven't checked in detail, but am pretty sure this theorem holds only in $\mathbf{R}^3$. (It's certainly false for circles in $\mathbf{R}^2$.)

Comment: Thanks! Where can i find this theorem?

Comment: It's a straightforward calculus exercise. :) I first came across it in one of the Marsden-Weinstein calculus books.

Comment: Yep, that's true. In any case, it would be nice to know how to extend it to higher dimensions/codimensions...